# JPA java code generation

Tags: java, jpa, autocomplete, templates, code-generation

I am specifically looking for JPA code generation technique

First, what are all the project could generate JPA compliant code? (Eg. HibernateTools)

Second, I would also like to customize the code generation utility, as it has to compliant to our corporate standards.

If not, what are all the framework available to generate java code using reflection? so I can write from scratch.

Note: I used eclipse to generate JPA code and refactor it repeatedly to make it compliant.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I also have difficulties understanding the question, but I'll try to rephrase:

- You have a lot of data in a DB and want to access it via JPA
- You don't want to manually write the classes to access the different DBs/tables
- Currently all/most of your model classes are generated from within Eclipse
- These models have JPA annotations
- The model classes (or the annotations) are not according to corporate standards

When you say "JPA java code generation", I understand generating JPA annotated model classes from a supplied DB connection. Most frameworks often refer to this as reverse engineering.

Now you have two questions:

1. What code generators can be recommended to generate JPA annotated classes?
2. Is it possible to customize the output of these frameworks, and in which way?

To answer to the first question:

- [Hibernate Tools](http://tools.hibernate.org) - already mentioned in the question, but I prefer this one
- [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/)
- [Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/BestPracticesWithJPAAndBeansBinding)

I really like the Netbeans code generation, especially if you show the results to someone not familiar with JPA.

At the level of customization I can only share the experience I had with Hibernate Tools. Especially for reproducible results, try to use the [ant-based tasks](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.0.0.CR1/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#ant). You can easily add some targets to your build and code generation can be done at two levels:

- Configure exporters using [properties](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.0.0.CR1/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#d0e3669)
- Provide custom [freemarker templates](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)

With the templates you should be able to cover most of the corporate standards. Look into the `pojo` directory of the hibernate-tools package. The easiest way to customize the code generation is to copy and adapt the templates and have them put before the hibernate-tools.jar in the ant task used to create the pojos.

As already pointed out in another comment, it might be difficult to modify the generated code afterwards. I hope the following tips can help you:

- Try to separate generated and customized source files in different folders.
- Think about using `@MappedSuperclass` for classes which you may want to adapt in a manual step.

Answer (score 5):

Another efficient solution for JPA code generation is "**Telosys Tools**"

An **Eclipse plugin** working from an existing database ( "database firts" approach ) with **customizable templates**. This solution is more flexible than Dali thanks to its lightweight model and the Velocity templates (shared on GitHub )

See the web site : http://www.telosys.org/

The plugin on Eclipse Marketplace : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/telosys-tools

A brief description of the principle : http://labs.sogeti.com/code-generation-can-it-be-simple-and-pragmatic/

For **JPA generation**, use the **JPA templates** available on GitHub : https://github.com/telosys-templates-v3

Comment: The new URL for Telosys Templates is : https://github.com/telosys-tools/
The bundle for JPA is "persistence-jpa-TTversion"

Comment: Will try it if it works for me.. As I am new to JPA.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Dali Persistence Eclipse Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/), The tool is available for download via the [Indigo Java EE SR1 update site](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/).

After the plugin is installed, to make a reverse engineering of your DB, you need to create a new JPA project, set database connection, launch the automated download of JPA runtime (in my case Eclipse Link), then start the generation process.

During the code generation process you're asked to provide details on table mappings and generated classes. At the end of the generation the code is clean.

Answer (score 2):

[Minuteproject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/) is a generator tool and can generate JPA1/ [JPA2](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/JPA2) as well as hibernate ORM-like artifacts.
It is based on reverse-engineering from the database.
You can instruct the generator to apply convention for your java code that do not follow your DB convention, but the mapping will be correct. (Example strip DB name prefix; table starting with ADMIN_ such as ADMIN_ENVIRONMENT are Environment (w/out Admin) as java class)
For the moment there [20+ conventions](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Configuration) that help you reshape your model to be less DB look-and-feel by more Java-OO-friendly.

Another interesting feature is [updatable-code](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Updatable_Generated_Code) enabling to modify both the generated code and your model **AND** aht the next generation **your modifications will be kept!** The generator makes the merge.

The templates are opensource and work with velocity, it is 'quite' easy to append a track to make specific one for your framework (ex security aspects... that are relevant to your organisation). You can scope your template to field level, entity (table or view), package (group of entities), model, application providing flexibility, and since the template of a track knows each other via metadata it is quite easy to reference then from other templates and to associate them by configuration with naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Project lombok seems allowing you to generate basic named queries, this is another approach using annotations and code generation at compile time.

See:

- http://groups.google.com/group/project-lombok/browse_thread/thread/a8c01b2226c081cb
- http://projectlombok.org

A guy over the hibernate forum seems using a traditionnal code generation approach with Hibernate Tools :
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=962223&p=2315766&hilit=named+queries+generate#p2315766

I agree with cletus on the point that you cannot generate all named queries, but I guess we can imagine generating basic named queries such finders based on one or several fields of the object.

Answer (score 0):

check out [JPM2java](https://jpm2java.java.net/), Its a code generator for JPA. The only catch is it does not generate JPA code from SQL files or table, you'd need a orm.xml file. If you are looking for a tool to generate code directly from tables, you may want to try Netbeans. It has options to generate JPA code directly from tables

Answer (score 0):

The ideal tool/eclipse plugin for jpa code reverse generation is Hibernate Tools. This has now been made a part of JBoss Tools. So, in your eclipse start off with installing JBoss Tools.

Then create a JPA Project. This project will act as the holder of all your code/configurations related to the reverse generation project. Installing the JBoss Tools first gives you the advantage that your Hibernate Configuration(part of Hibernate Tools) gets created along with your JPA project.

Next step would be to use the Hibernate Tools to actually reverse generate your JPA POJO entities corresponding to your database tables.

To understand the steps for JPA POJO reverse generation in detail you can have a look at the following tutorial...http://www.javabrahman.com/j2ee/how-to-do-reverse-code-generation-of-hibernatejpa-pojo-entities-using-jboss-tools-eclipse-plugin/

The above tutorial also has links to tutorials for creating a JPA Project and also for installing JBoss Tools in your eclipse installation both of which are pre-requisites for JPA POJO entities reverse code generation.

Answer (score 0):

Open source graphical tool to generate JPA class, visualize & modify Database, reverse engineering exiting source code and import models from existing database.

For NetBeans : http://jpamodeler.github.io/
For Eclipse : https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look on JOOQ.

http://www.jooq.org/

Open Source is available .....

Comment: What kind of examples? Can you reproduce one here?

Answer (score -5):

Ok, basically you have things the wrong way arond: `JPA is the generation tool`.

I say this because the only thing you could generate JPA entities from is SQL and the whole point of JPA is to do things the other way around.  You define your object model first and, from that, you can generate your tables and queries.

For example, I've seen projects use Hibernate to define their entities and then they have an ant build script that creates the database from the Hibernate entity model.

JPA entity definitions--especially done with annotations--aren't exactly onerous.  They really are your best option as the first thing to do rather than being the product of something else.

Besides, another tool won't help you write named queries, define the correct cascade options on relationships, etc.  And if you had generated code, how would you handle modifying it afterwards?

It's just not the right way to go.

Comment: This answer was downvoted because approaching the problem from either side is acceptable and both have tradeoffs