# How to generate entity classes from database in java

Tags: java, .net, orm, entity, pojo

I have been used to generating entity classes from database in .net. But recently i begun work on java and I have been looking for ways to do the same with hibernate or any other ORM tool. I havent yet found a way to do the same, all I find is that generate xml mappings or use java annotations.

Am i missing something here, it used to be a very easy approach in .net. You figure out your data model, create a database and then generate the entity classes using Entity Framework. It took care of generating classes for foreign key mappings as well.

In java, on the other hand, I have to manually map all the tables and their fields.

Comment: You can do the same e.g., in [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). Plenty of samples in the documentation to help you get started.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452627/jpa-java-code-generation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables

Comment: I was following the same steps over and over again but wasnt able to generate the classes. That is until I realized the problem was elsewhere. I was using AWS RDS instance as my database server and while trying to connect to it from eclipse using data source explorer it did not show the tables. So i tried connecting to the local database server and it worked just fine.

Comment: as an after thought, If you are just moving to java technologies, i would suggest reading up frameworks like Groovy on Grails (or Ruby on Rails). Read about Convention Over Configuration. Its Hassle free programming!

Comment: I kinda dont have an option right now. But in future I am going to get into RoR on my own for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The DB reverse engineering plugin of Spring Roo, [Spring Roo DBRE](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html), can do this if Spring and Spring Roo would fit your needs. Generating foreign key mappings also worked good for me. Spring Roo also offers web scaffold generation.